# WebRTC error on voe_audio_processing_impl.cc:857

Tags: android, webrtc, sinch

When in a call using the Sinch SDK on Android, the following error is thrown:

```
09-14 17:06:38.223  28454-28484/com.callcasual.callcasual E/sinch-android-rtc﹕ ERROR     ; (17: 6:38:237 |    1)                               28493; (voe_audio_processing_impl.cc:857): GetEcMetricsStatus: not supported
```

When searching for that error it appears to be an issue with WebRTC, however I cannot find a way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only indicating that `echo metrics` are not available, the voice will go through fine during the call anyway. Why WebRTC logs this as an error I'm not sure but we are looking at disabling this in a future release of the Sinch SDK.

Comment: That's strange, we aren't hearing sound on either end of the call.